# Tapestry 5 cannot resolve symbol "layout"

Tags: java, tapestry

I´m trying to get a simple Tapestry sample working, but I´m getting stuck at the very beginning.

I want to declare my first tml page, which I have from the official tapestry site (not yet allowed to post links).

```
<html t:type="layout" t:id="index" xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd ">

<h1>Welcome to the Nifty Web Application!</h1>

<p>
 Would you like to
<t:pagelink page="login">Log In</t:pagelink>
?
</p>
</html>
```

It says "cannot resolve symbol layout" and "cannot resolve symbol login" and I also tried commonLayout which can´t be found too, but there are many other types showing up in the auto completion, which means that in general there is everything okay with the library stuff.

I´ve added every dependency from the sample.

Is layout kind of deprecated or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

You are more likely to get help on the Tapestry mailing list.

And you are more likely to get help by *reporting the exact error* that Tapestry produces. Trust me, a lot of work has gone into making that information valuable, please include it. For example, I can pretty much guarantee that the errors you cite are not the actual error messages Tapestry produced.

That being said, Tapestry does not include a Layout component, since it is one of the most application specific parts of any application. It is something you build yourself. There are tutorials, or the Tapestry Maven archetype includes a basic one.

Likewise, there is no built-in Login page. That's a pretty standard thing you build in yourself as well.

Tapestry is infrastructure, not magic.

Comment: It´s not an error tapestry produces but an error my IDE produces. With that errors I can´t even run that thing.